# jQuery-File-Upload not work with iframeupload and multiple file selection

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I get some problem with the blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload plugin.
I set the option 'forceIframeTransport' to 'true' ,when add multiple file selection ,only the first file could be uploaded. I check browser request ,only first file submitted for each add opreation. How can I resolve the problem.

this is my options:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({

    forceIframeTransport : true,
    url : '${rc.contextPath}/file/lib/upload',
    type : 'POST',
    autoUpload : false,
    data : {
        catId : '${catId!}',
        type : '${type!}'
    },
    sequentialUploads : true,
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all for accessing iframe elements you can use this :

```
$("iframe").contents().find('#fileupload').fileupload({
    forceIframeTransport : true,
    url : '${rc.contextPath}/file/lib/upload',
    type : 'POST',
    autoUpload : false,
data : {
         catId : '${catId!}',
         type : '${type!}'
     },
sequentialUploads : true,
```